# how to order by a substring regexp?

Tags: sqlite

I have a string column that is something like 'foo.bar.baz123' and I would like to order on the integer at the end of that string so..  In postgres, I can do this with:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(column FROM '(\d+)$')::integer
```

But how do you do it in sqlite?

Also, I should note that it's important to order by integer so that I'd get results sorted like:

```
foo.bar.baz1
foo.bar.baz2
foo.bar.baz10
foo.bar.baz123
```

Comment: Will the number at the end always contain 3 digits, or could that vary?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, see my updated question.. there will be 1-n digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution should work assuming that the `column` field always is of the form `foo.bar.bazXYZ`, where `XYZ` contains one or more digits.

```
SELECT column
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(column,
                     INSTR(column, 'baz') + 3,
                     LENGTH(REPLACE(column, 'foo.bar.baz', ''))) AS INTEGER) ASC;
```